# VBA - showing wrong results

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across a issue while working in VBA . I'm supposed to write program that is Numerical integration of trapeze method (I'm not sure if It is how it's called in English) of function 100*x^99 lower limit = 0 upper limit = 1 . Cells (j,5) contains numbers (10,30,100,300,1000,3000,10000) - amount of point splits . Code seems to work but given wrong results , for amount of splits it should be around

10 - 5.000295129200607
30 - 1.786588019299606
100 - 1.0812206997600746
300 - 1.0091505687770146
1000 - 1.0008248693208752
3000 - 1.0000916650530287
10000 - 1.000008249986933

```
Function F(x) 
F = 100 * (x ^ 99)
End Function  
Sub calka()

Dim n As Single
Dim xp As Single
Dim dx As Single
Dim xk As Single
Dim ip As Single

Dim pole As Single

xp = 0
xk = 1
For j = 5 To 11

n = Cells(j, 5)
dx = (xk - xp) / n



pole = 0
For i = 1 To n - 1
 pole = pole + F(xp + i * dx)
Next i

pole = pole + ((F(xp) + F(xk)) / 2)
pole = pole * dx






Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(j, 7) = pole

Next j

End Sub
```

I tried to implement same code in java and c++ and it worked flawlessly but VBA always gives me wrong results , I'm not sure if it's rounds at some point and I can disable in settings or my code is just not written right .
Apologies for low clarity It's hard for me to translate mathematic to English.

Comment: did you use single in c++ and java?

Comment: "trapeze method" is usually called "the trapezoid rule" (or something similar) in English. Your `xk` seems to never change.

Comment: I feel so dumb , I wasted few hours since I didn't even realize that I was using Integrers instead of Doubles . Also xk is supposed to never change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Doubles rather than  Singles

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/comparing-double-vs-single-data-types-in-vb6/

Comment: While that is good advice, it is unlikely to be the issue here.

Comment: Mightn't it be one of the issues, however?  Assigning e.g. 5.000295129200607 to a single results in a variable containing 5.000295 where assigning it to a double results in 5.00029512920061 (still rounded!)